image not displaying when using imagebutton or button in .net maui
these are the codes below. I am using visual studio 2022. Tried lot of things in .xaml file like changed build action for image property and changed folder. but still not displaying.
<Button ImageSource="2.png" Background="Aqua" WidthRequest="600" HeightRequest="600"/>  


    
<ImageButton Source="logo.png" HeightRequest="500" WidthRequest="500" Margin="10,10"/>

when i tried default image in code (code mentioned below). image will be displaying.
<ImageButton Source="dotnet_bot.png" HeightRequest="500" WidthRequest="500" Margin="10,10"/>
           


Does this work with Image?

The only difference that's apparent between those two ImageButton nodes is the file name. You might need to create a simple 1 or 2 item XAML file that can demonstrate the problem and be posted on internet.

You're not providing sufficient information. Where did you add the image in your project? Instead of writing "I tried XYZ", show what you did as this helps others help you.

First, you can check if you put the images in the Resources/Images folder. Then you can change the Build Action of the image to the MauiImage.
By using this way, you can create the imagebutton like this.
<ImageButton Source="pic.png" HeightRequest="500" WidthRequest="500" Margin="10,10"/>

